# Issue with brownie

Tags: web3.py, brownie

When I run brownie, I get the following error message.

```
root@DESKTOP-MIQQV4H:/mnt/c/users/user/documents/blockchain/brownie_simple_storage# nvm install 16.13.2
v16.13.2 is already installed.
Now using node v16.13.2 (npm v8.1.2)
root@DESKTOP-MIQQV4H:/mnt/c/users/user/documents/blockchain/brownie_simple_storage# node --version
v16.13.2
root@DESKTOP-MIQQV4H:/mnt/c/users/user/documents/blockchain/brownie_simple_storage# brownie run scripts/deploy.py
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieSimpleStorageProject is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli --port 8545 --gasLimit 12000000 --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --mnemonic brownie'...
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 50, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 53, in run
    module = _import_from_path(script)
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 149, in _import_from_path
    _import_cache[import_str] = importlib.import_module(import_str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mnt.c.Users.user'
Terminating local RPC client...
```

**Issue resolved

Now I run into the following:

```
root@DESKTOP-MIQQV4H:/mnt/c/users/user/documents/Blockchain/brownie_fund_me# brownie run scripts/deploy.py
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieFundMeProject is the active project.
  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 44, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "brownie/network/main.py", line 48, in connect
    rpc.attach(host)
  File "brownie/network/rpc/__init__.py", line 113, in attach
    pid = self._find_rpc_process_pid(resolved_addr)
  File "brownie/network/rpc/__init__.py", line 194, in _find_rpc_process_pid
    return self._get_pid_from_net_connections(laddr)
  File "brownie/network/rpc/__init__.py", line 234, in _get_pid_from_net_connections
    raise ProcessLookupError(
ProcessLookupError: Could not attach to RPC process by querying 'proc.net_connections()'
```

I tried to make an exception in firewall for port 8545 like someone suggested. But to no avail.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the later question, I guess you're using brownie from Windows WSL.

I've got similar problem and submitted a PR several months ago

https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/pull/1303

Maybe this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

When brownie inits, it prints to console file path data, e.g: /mnt/c/users/..

Note in the error message the capital U in Users, yet, console reported users folder was all lower case:

```
Error message No module named 'mnt.c.Users.user'
```

Comment: Awesome, that solved it. Can I ask, why does it make an uppercase of Users, and not of user?

Comment: I don't know why, would have to look at brownie's code for parsing file paths. On a side note, on stackoverflow/stackexchange you accept the answer by clicking the checkmark under the question. Helps the people who made an effort to help. cheers.

Comment: Ah perfect, I was looking for that actually ^^

Comment: Should I change all my path to lowercase?